How to remove square brackets in wordpress post?
I got this echo doo_isset($postmeta,'youtube_id');
and return this result in Wordpress post: [iNJaoIZTHh0]
Can please help me to remove the square brackets for result to be only: iNJaoIZTHh0
I tried to find something useful on other websites but nothing until now.
PS. Thanks C3roe, right answer is:
echo trim(doo_isset($postmeta,'youtube_id'), '[]');

Have you tried str_replace?

I tried:


but is not working ...

If you have any code related to your question, please edit the question itself, don't just post comments.

I'm fairly certain you will not be able to solve this in JavaScript. I would look into do_shortcode along with the embed shortcode.

echo trim(doo_isset($postmeta,'youtube_id'), '[]');
